# Duplicates are being removed from my object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to create 2 arrays and 1 object. One array contains the names the user has entered (using multiple forms) and the other contains numbers assigned to those names (using dropdown buttons). The object is generated using the names as keys and the numbers as values.

The issue that I am having is that, in the final object, all duplicates from the initial arrays seem to be removed. Listed below this text is the JSON output that I have been receiving.

**(3) ["jennifer", "jennifer", "michelle"]** - Console.log() of the names looks good
**(3)** **[1, 3, 2]** - Console.log() of the numbers looks good
**{jennifer: 3, michelle: 2}** - The object only contains one of the Jennifers when there should be 2.

***{jennifer: 1, jennifer: 3, michelle: 2}*** - This is what the output should look like. My code is listed below.

```
    // Gather the names that were entered and dump them into an array
   var names = $("input[name='name']")
    .map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();


  // Gather the access level assigned to those names and dump them into an array.
  var accessLevel = $("button[name='options']").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();



  // Create an object containing the key [name] value [access level] pairs
  var result = {};
  names.forEach((key, i) => result[key] = accessLevel[i]);
```

***Thank you all for your help!***

Comment: Of course, objects are collections of unique properties (no duplicates can exist).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects are collections of unique properties, they are not suitable if your key (?) is not unique (not really a key then). Note that even if you did this:

```
var result = {jennifer: 1, jennifer: 3, michelle: 2};
```

... the result would still be:

```
{jennifer: 3, michelle: 2}
```

#### A way out

For your case, you could bring both arrays into one data structure as follows:

```
// Create an array containing the key [name] and value [access level] pairs
var result = names.map((name, i) => ({ name, accessLevel: accessLevel[i]}));
```

This will produce:

```
[
    { name: "jennifer", accessLevel: 1 },
    { name: "michelle", accessLevel: 2 },
    { name: "jennifer", accessLevel: 3 }
]
```

Comment: You are exactly right, I should not be using key/value pairs for this. Your solution worked exactly as I needed. Thank you for your knowledge and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two of the same keys in an object. That's not how an object works. Maybe what you want to do is have each key in the object be an array of numbers:

```
{ jennifer: [0, 2], jan: [1] }
```